# collect sequences in list in python

Tags: python, search, sequence, subsequence

Assuming that I have a sorted list:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20,23,25,26,27]
```

How can I get subsequence in `a` like:

```
[(1,2,3,4,5,6),(10,11,12,13,14,15,16),20,23,(25,26,27)]
```

Comment: So, to clarify, you're grouping the consecutive integers together into tuples?

Comment: Does sequence mean all values that have a difference of 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20,23,25,26,27]

lst = []
last = None

for item in a:
    if last is None:
        current = [item]
    elif item - last == 1:
        current.append(item)
    else:
        if 1 == len(current):
            lst.append(current[0])
        else:
            lst.append(tuple(current))
        current = [item]
    last = item
lst.append(tuple(current))

print(lst)
```

output:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), 20, 23, (25, 26, 27)]
```